# Spring 4 validation not working

Tags: java, spring

I created form and I want to validate values posted from this form. Here is my code:

registerForm.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spittr</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br/>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

bean:

```
package spitter;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Spitter {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=16)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=25)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public Spitter() {}

    public Spitter(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this(null, username, password, firstName, lastName, email);
    }

    public Spitter(Long id, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, that, "firstName", "lastName", "username", "password", "email");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, "firstName", "lastName", "username", "password", "email");
    }
}
```

request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=POST)
public String processRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, BindingResult errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "registerForm";
    }

    repository.save(spitter);
    return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUsername();
}
```

my problem is that regardless of input in form validation always pass. Have you any idea how can I fix it?

BTW: I use Spring 4 and totally xml-free configuration.

Comment: Add `@ModelAttribute` to your `Spitter` method argument.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly I should put @ModelAttribute ?

Comment: I already did on the `Spitter` method argument next to the `@Valid` annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt help :(

Comment: Then really make sure that the validation api is on your class path and that you have enabled it correctly in your configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In registerForm.jsp in the input you need to tag each one appropriately. Also, you need to put some kind of tag for the actual error if there is one. For example:

```
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" th:field="*{firstName)">
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">First Name Error</p>
```

Check out the Spring Validation docs! (http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)